# phpunit break tests to suites, by actions, DB, queue simple

Tags: php, filter, phpunit

I have several tests on different modules and some of them on diffent services.

For example I have the: "User" & "payment" modules.

Now each of them has its own unit tests, and tests for talking with the DB.

I want to have 3 suites: User, Payment & DbConnectors

the third one will check only the tests with connection to DB

Any idea how to use that power>

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the tests that talk to the DB using the `@group` annotation:

```
/**
 * @group database
 */
public function testWriteIntoDatabase()
{

}
```

When invoking PHPUnit you can filter or exclude the database tests by using the `--group` and `--exclude-group` options.

This can be used in conjunction with testsuites.

More info in [the docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group).